# credit card payment expressJS

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

hello guys currently i am stuck on payments with nodejs and i googled it and most of tutorials are using Stripe, my question: is stripe safe ? i want to implement something like netflix payment, it takes X amount of $ from credit card every month
can it be implemented with stripe, or there is more advanced payment library or module (in npm). ***thank you***

if you can please link tutorial for the most used,safe and user-friendly payment system for nodejs and exprssjs (and if it matters for MongoDB(mongoose) too)

Comment: Hi Jake, yes Stripe is safe to use; as a matter of fact Deliveroo, Lyft, Amazon, Doordash etc. are all using Stripe. 

Stripe has an official node library (https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node) and frontend widget for you to use. Stripe document is very easy to follow. To get started, you could simple register an account at stripe.com and follow the document at https://stripe.com/docs/quickstart; You are doing subscriptions, you could use the billing feature there as well https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart

Comment: thank you so much, and does stripe has monthly payment implementation or it should be implemented in nodejs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripe is a really good payment system, you can definitely use if for this purpose. There are other systems out there as well of course, but Stripe is certainly one of the better ones.

Check out this library:
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node

There's also a nice tutorial from Stripe here:
https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/express

Comment: does stripe has monthly payment implementation or it should be implemented with nodejs?

Comment: Yes, it's called subscription I believe, you can set it up to charge on the 1st of each month for example.

Comment: check out below link

https://rubygarage.org/blog/stripe-vs-braintree-vs-paypal-how-do-these-payment-platforms-compare

Comment: Here's some more info on subscriptions: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/creating

Comment: in rubygarage link people in comments are giving bad feedback i confused by the way

Comment: You'll get that with a lot of products of course, and each payment system will have its own problems. I would do a little bit of your own research, play with some of the options. See what the pros and cons are for each. Maybe create a short list of 5 providers say and see what's involved.